# Ubuntu 18 autologin only works if monitor is on

Tags: 18.04, login, xorg, lightdm, auto-login

I have autologin enable in Ubuntu 18 and it only works if my monitor is powered on, otherwise it will not login.

I asked a similar question recently and realised that it wasn't a consistent non-login but only when display was off hence this new post. As stated there:

- I have a Cron job to shut down each night and the BIOS powers it on in the morning.
- I have enabled the autologin option in Settings and edited /etc/gdm3/custom.conf as suggested in https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-automatic-login-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux
- When editing custom.conf I have tried with and without spaces for AutomaticLoginEnable = true and my username
- I have no xorg.conf file
- I have RealVNC host installed (not sure if relevant but as it links to display so thought I'd add this)
- switching to use LightDM did not work, system would not boot into Ubuntu Desktop although I could SSH in

The last answer suggested it may be something crashing my X Stack and causing there to be no X server but I'm not sure how to diagnose or test.

Monitor is connected via HDMI from the motherboard display out, not a separate GPU.

Comment: Check /var/log/syslog for errors that occurred around login time.

Comment: thanks @user535733 looking at the errors I'm seeing a lot of variants on:

`Feb 21 05:59:37  /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1847]: (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.`

`Feb 21 05:59:37 gdm3: GdmDisplay: Failed to read kernel commandline: Could not match gnome.initial-setup= in kernel cmdline`

`Feb 21 05:59:37 gdm-launch-environment]: AccountsService: Failed to identify the current session: No data available`

Comment: Which is odd as answers suggest I should edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf to have `WaylandEnable=False`, which I do.